# WSS and SSL certificate issues in Android

Tags: android, websocket, ssl-certificate, java-websocket

I am trying to connect to a websocket having wss protocol. I tried the AutoBahn library and able to connect to wss://echo.websocket.org but when I am trying to connect to our server, I am getting 403 (Forbidden) error. We have our own SSL certificate provided by GoDaddy. The socket connection works perfectly fine from iOS devices and browsers but not on Android.

I have also tried bypassing the SSL certificates and creating my own.

As it's security related, can't put the wss link of our server here.

Logs as requested

```
10-20 14:03:53.831 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: WebSocket connection created.
10-20 14:03:54.107 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: WebSocket reader created.
10-20 14:03:54.109 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: WebSocket reader created and started.
10-20 14:03:54.114 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: WebSocket writer created.
10-20 14:03:56.153 16402-16617/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: WebSocker reader running.
10-20 14:03:56.158 16402-16618/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: WebSocker writer running.
10-20 14:03:56.158 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: WebSocket writer created and started.
10-20 14:03:56.165 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo W/Performance: More than 500 ms to handle , msg.target = Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {c6fab6} , msg.callback = android.view.View$PerformClick@3e063b7, msg.what = 0 , takenTime = 2338 , startTime = 408345922
10-20 14:03:56.167 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo I/Choreographer: Skipped 140 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-20 14:03:56.466 16402-16617/com.cameronpalmer.echo W/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: Status: 403 (Forbidden)
10-20 14:03:56.467 16402-16617/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: WebSocket reader ended.
10-20 14:03:56.467 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: fail connection [code = SERVER_ERROR, reason = Server error 403 (Forbidden)
10-20 14:03:56.467 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: quit
10-20 14:03:56.468 16402-16618/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: WebSocket writer ended.
10-20 14:03:56.470 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/com.cameronpalmer.echo.EchoActivity: Close: SERVER_ERROR, Server error 403 (Forbidden)
10-20 14:03:56.471 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: worker threads stopped
10-20 14:03:56.471 16402-16402/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: opening handshake received
10-20 14:03:56.471 16402-16611/com.cameronpalmer.echo D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: SocketThread exited.
```

Comment: show your relevant error logs.

Comment: Post your code in which you are passing the certificates. Also does your server has basic auth or any type of authentication that you might be missing?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - I have tried the 4th option mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872

Comment: You downloaded the certificate in BKS or Base64 format?

Comment: I downloaded the certificate from our server, created .pem and then exported to .bks

Comment: Then this problem is not related to certificate authentication.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - I suspect that our server is not authenticating the request for some reason. Handshake is completed but then the authentication fails.

Comment: Do your server implement any kind of authentication? like basic, oauth etc?